# ngclick not working in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]This is my html code

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified th-menu">
                    <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:isActive('/about')}"  ><a href="#/about" ng-click="scrollToSection('content-section')">Erafone offer details</a></li>
                    <li role="presentation" ng-class="{active:isActive('/form')}"><a href="#/form" ng-click="scrollToSection('content-section')">Form</a></li>
                </ul>
```

And this is my angular js code

```
$scope.scrollToSection = function(sectionID){

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#"+sectionID).offset().top  - 63
    }, 800);
}

}]);
```

I am new to angular js and I want to know how to I switch between views using ng click?? If anyone has idea regarding this then please guide me.

**There are 4 tabs. I want when user click on form tab, form should be loaded on same page.**

Comment: You have an ng-click event attached to your nav button. May be this click event is ceasing the propagation of click event.

Comment: It seems you have a single page and you need to scroll to form element on that page. Its better to use ngInclude directive in this case and include your form template.

Comment: Can you create a plnkr or jsfiddle link and share it with us. It would enable us to solve your problem

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/96dpjbe6/

Comment: Why do you always pass "content-section" as argument?

Comment: Do you observe scrollToSEction function in js??

Answer (score 0):

Yup.  The `href` attribute takes precedence over `ng-click`.

One option is to leave the `href` blank...

```
<a href ng-click="scrollToSection('content-section')">Form</a>
```

You could then include the code to switch views in the `scrollToSection` function (although, you might want to rethink your function name at this point...) with the following...

```
$location.path('/form');
```